# HTML Drag and Drop... Can Drag But Not Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

My end goal with this project is to basically have a spreadsheet (really just a giant HTML table) with the contenteditable value set to true. The other thing I need is to be able to create an input box, and drag it anywhere on the screen, including on the spreadsheet. Right now, whenever I try to drag an input box, it gives me the little red circle with a line through it in the top right corner of the box, telling me that I can't drop it anywhere.

My HTML is so long because it's a huge spreadsheet, but with a couple hundred fewer rows, it basically looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addTileButton").click(function() {
    $("body").append("<div id=draggable></div>");
    var tile = $("<form><input id=tile draggable=true type=text> </form>");
    $("#draggable").append(tile);
    $("#tile").draggable();
  });
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #tile {
    cursor: move;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<button id="addTileButton">Click to add tile</button>
<div contenteditable="true" id="tableDiv">
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <colgroup width="509"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="5" width="166"></colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">State Name</font></b>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">GA (P)</font></b>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">C.3</font></b>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">ExCom</font></b>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">HRC</font></b>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">SC</font></b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Afghanistan</td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Albania</td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Algeria</td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font>
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - I don't need the generated element to be an input field. It just has to be an element that can have text in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a droppable div

```
<div id="droppable"> 
  ...
</div>
```

And in Jquery

```
 $("#droppable").droppable();
```

Comment: While that does seem like it would work correctly... it doesn't. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Did you provide some height and width to the div?Did you get the same error? btw you can also try $("body").droppable(); if you want it to be droppable anywhere...

Comment: I'll try $("body").droppable();. I figured that the width/height of the div would increase with the addition of each box, but I'll try setting some values. Thanks again!